# Angularjs Twitter Bootstrap Directives -- Tabs

Tags: angularjs

I have successfully implemented tabs in a modal with the Angular directives for TB. I have been trying to figure out from the documentation how to make certain things happen when a tab is clicked. No success yet.

**View**

```
<tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" active="tab.active" heading="{{tab.title}}" disabled="tab.disabled" >
            <div ng-include="tab.content"></div>
        </tab>
    </tabs>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.tabs = [
        { title:"Home", content:"/beta/application/views/images/uploader/create.html", active: true },
        { title:"Upload", content:"/beta/application/views/images/uploader/upload.html"},
        { title:"Edit", content:"/beta/application/views/images/uploader/edit.html"}
    ];
```

There is a ng-click="select()", leaving me to think I could call the following.

```
$scope.select = function () {
    console.log('testing');
};
```

Obviously I am wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're talking about the [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) tabs and I think you are talking about the select attribute on the directive.

If you put the select="scopeMethod()" on the tab directive, and define the controller method like so:

```
$scope.scopeMethod = function(){
  //Do something meaningful
  alert("You clicked this tab");
}
```

the method will fire when you click on that tab.

This should also work for tabs that are created within an ng-repeat. See [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8d9smcVnX35RI0YGEnAn)

Comment: your assumptions are correct. Using the ng-repeat, do you know what the best option is for firing a method for a particular tab? -- thanks

Comment: Apparently, I was wrong. This should also work on tabs within an ng-repeat. See my edit and link to the plunker.

Comment: thanks man, solid answer and clears up some other issues as well. Thanks